# Is there a better way for me to architect this batch processing pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, concurrency, amazon-rds, batch-processing, aws-batch

So I have a large dataset (1.5 Billion) I need to perform a I/O bound transform task on (same task for each point) and place the result into a store that allows fuzzy searching on the transforms fields.

What I currently have is a Step-Function Batch Job Pipeline feeding into RDS. It works like so

1. Lamba splits input data into X number of even partitions
2. An Array Batch job is created with X array elements matching the X paritions
3. Batch jobs (1 vCPU, 2048 Gb ram) run on  number of EC2 spot instances, transform the data and place it into RDS.

This current solution (with X=1600 workers) runs in about 20-40 minutes, mainly based on the time it takes to spin up spot instance jobs. The actual jobs themselves average about 15 minutes in run time. As for total cost, with spot savings the workers cost ~40 bucks but the real kicker is the RDS postgres DB. To be able to handle 1600 concurrent writes you need at least a r5.xlarge which is 500 a month!

Therein lies my problem. It seems I could run the actual workers quicker and for cheaper ( due to second based pricing) by having say 10,000 workers but then I would need a RDS system that could handle 10,000 concurrent DB connections somehow.

I've looked high and low and can't find a good solution to this scaling wall I am hitting. Below I'll detail some things I've tried and why they haven't worked for me or don't seem like a good fit.

1. RDS proxies - I tried creating 2 proxies set to 50% connection pool and giving "Even" numbered jobs one proxy and odd numbered jobs the other but that didn't help
2. DynamoDb - This seems off the bat to solve my problem hugely concurrent, can definitely handle the write load but it doesn't allow fuzzy searching like `select * where field LIKE Y` which is a key part of my workflow with the batch job results
3. (Theory) - have the jobs write their results to S3 then trigger a lambda on new bucket entries to insert those into the DB. (This might be a terrible idea I'm not sure)

Anyways, what I'm after is improving the cost of running this batch pipeline (mainly the DB), improving the time to run (to save on Spot costs) or both! I am open to any feedback or suggestion!

Let me know if there's some key piece of info you need I missed.

Comment: Why not just limit the parallelism to whatever your db instance can handle, by having it process the jobs sequentially in N parallel streams? It'd take longer, but wouldn't cost more in terms of compute

Comment: This is a textbook map-reduce problem. Have you considered something like Spark running on EMR?